# Batch file to replace a line

Tags: string, batch-file, line

Many examples here for replace subsring or string, but i need replace all line what contains some string with another line with constant text. For example i have a file:

```
aaa=111
bbb=222
ccc=333
aaa=444
```

I need to replace "aaa=" to "aaa=000". The output file should look like this:

```
aaa=000
bbb=222
ccc=333
aaa=000
```

All this must be done without party tools like sed,awk,etc

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `for` loop to parse each line of the file.  If `"!line:~0,4!"=="aaa="` then echo out your desired replacement, else echo the line untouched.  These echos should be [redirected](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) to a text file.  Then when you're done, move the newly composed text file over top of the file you've been looping through.

A common method for looping through a text file while preserving empty lines is `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%I in ('findstr /n "^" "filename.txt"') do ( something with %%J )`  That `findstr` command will output every line in the file, including blank lines, with a line number at the beginning of the line.  `%%J` becomes whatever is after the line number on each line.

This should be enough to get you started.  Good luck!